# skip the iteration in the loop

Tags: r, loops, compare

I have 2 cycles in which I count

```
for(i in 1:15){
  for(j in 1:5){
    bact_1 <- compare_means(value~group, data = list_control[[i]][[j]],method = 'wilcox.test',paired = TRUE)
}
}
```

at some steps, `value == NA`

My question is how to skip these steps when `value == NA`

What did I do:

```
for(i in 1:15){
  for(j in 1:5){
    if(is.na(list_control[[i]][[j]][2])){
      bact_1=0
      }
    else{
    bact_1 <- compare_means(value~group, data = list_control[[i]][[j]],method = 'wilcox.test',paired = TRUE)}
}
}
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work, except that you don't pass 0 but skip it completely

```
for(i in 1:15){
  for(j in 1:5){
    if(!is.na(list_control[[i]][[j]][2])){
      compare_means(value~group, data = list_control[[i]][[j]],method = 'wilcox.test',paired = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Also note that in your code you rewrite the results in each iteration, saving the results to the same variable bact_1.